# Harmonic function 2

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $P$ be a harmonic function

show that  : $$\Delta P = 4\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z\partial \overline{z}}$$

I have no idea how to even start, please if someone can push me in the right way that would be great.

Comment: What is the domain and codomain of $P$?

Comment: the domain is $D$ (it is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$)
and the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If P is harmonic, then it also satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. By taking the appropriate derivates and doing some algebra you should get the conclusion.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$? Also, do you know the definition of $\Delta$?

Comment: @ Michael Albanese yes and yes the thing that is bothering me is $\partial z\partial \overline{z}$

Comment: $$\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial\bar{z}}\right)$$

Comment: Compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}\right).$

Comment: @ Michael Albanese  it makes much more sense to me now so I should be able to solve it thank you for shedding light

Answer (score 2):

$$ x = \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}, \quad y = \frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}. $$
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \bar{z}} &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{z}} \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{z}} \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}  + \frac{i}{2} \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} - \frac{i}{2} \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x \partial y} \right) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y\partial x} - \frac{i}{2} \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}  \left( \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} - i \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x \partial y} \right) + \frac{i}{4} \left( \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y\partial x} - i \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \Delta P + \frac{i}{4} \left( \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y\partial x} - \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x\partial y} \right),
\end{align} $$
and the second term vanishes since $P$ is twice-differentiable.